# WPF Datagrid horizontal scrolling with only header data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `WPF` `Datagrid`, at initial stage i will assign 100 column header to `Datagrid`, but I am not able to horizontal scroll it to view all column headers.

`DataGrid` does not have any rows, `ItemSource` is null. How do I achieve horizontal scrolling when I have only column headers (no rows).

I binded `ItemSource` to a DataTable which has only column header and no rows.

How can I scroll in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ArsenMkrt said, it is not possible. But, I think you can add a row to your `DataTable` but after that, you can set its corresponding `DatagridRow`'s Visibility to be Hidden.

When your `DataTable` is being populated with actual data, just clear DataTable.Rows.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a workaround for this issue that worked for me: just place the `DataGrid` into a `ScrollViewer` and make a `DataTrigger` to set the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` of the `ScrollViewer` to `Visible` if `DataGrid` has no items.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ScrollViewer.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid, Path=HasItems}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ScrollViewer.Style>
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Here it is in C#:

var outerScroller = new ScrollViewer { Content = dataGrid, VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled, };
outerScroller.Style = new Style(typeof(ScrollViewer), outerScroller.Style) { Triggers = { new DataTrigger { Binding = new Binding("HasItems") { Source = dataGrid, }, Value = false, Setters = { new Setter(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Visible), }, }, }, };

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunetly it is not possible with DataGrid default style, you have to override template and create your custom grid derived to the main one. [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/64b18ca9-f9f5-4748-86a8-c5b40815fd9b) you can find more details.

Answer (score -1):

You don't. You have to have a row.

Change your ItemsSource to not default to null.

If you allow adding a row, you can default to an empty list.

If you don't allow adding a row, you need to default to a list of one item.

```
List<object> olist = new List<object>();
olist.add(new object());
```

Comment: I changed my ItemSource to a DataTable which only column headers, no rows. Even then I cannot scroll.

Comment: You didn't read my entire post it seems. The first line is clear that you have to have a row. I gave you two options for this: 1. Allow adding a row which means IsReadonly="False", which essentially adds an empty row or 2. you have to bind to a list with one item. But the workaround suggested by max works well. Are you trying to find a better solution?